# Removing a group with conditional statement in r

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, dplyr, conditional-statements

The conditional statement is that in any event, if there are two or more consecutive rows with values higher than 1, the group should be deleted.

For example:

```
Event<- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3)
Value<- c(1,0,0,0,8,7,1,0,0,0,8,0,0,0,0)
A<- data.frame(Event, Value)

Event   Value
  1       1
  1       0
  1       0
  1       0
  2       8
  2       7
  2       1
  2       0
  2       0
  2       0
  3       8
  3       0
  3       0
  3       0
  3       0
```

In this example the group of event 2 should be deleted because it has two consecutive rows with  values higher than 1. So it should looks like:

```
Event   Value
  1       1
  1       0
  1       0
  1       0
  3       8
  3       0
  3       0
  3       0
  3       0
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Yes, by more than 1.

Comment: If there are more than 1 consecutive rows of a group, with values >1 then I want to delete the group

Comment: Sorry, is with more than 1 consecutive row of a group. As it is shown in the example

Comment: Within a group, is it always the case that the values are descending, as they are in this example? Or could we have, for instance, in the same group: 3, 0, 1, 5 in that order (meaning the group should NOT be deleted because the numbers larger than 1 aren't consecutive)?

Comment: Not necessary. In your example (3,0,1,5) you are right, it should not be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `rle` by groups.

```
library(dplyr)
A %>%
 group_by(Event) %>%
 filter(!any(with(rle(Value > 1), lengths[values] > 1)))
 #Opposite way using all
 #filter(all(with(rle(Value > 1), lengths[values] < 2)))

#  Event Value
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     1
#2     1     0
#3     1     0
#4     1     0
#5     3     8
#6     3     0
#7     3     0
#8     3     0
#9     3     0
```

The same logic can be used in base R :

```
subset(A, !ave(Value > 1, Event, FUN = function(x) 
               any(with(rle(x), lengths[values] > 1))))
```

as well as `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(A)[, .SD[!any(with(rle(Value > 1), lengths[values] > 1))], Event]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`

```
A %>%
  group_by(Event) %>%
  mutate(consec = if_else(Value > 1, row_number(), 0L),
         remove = if_else(consec > 1,"Y","N")) %>%
  filter(!any(remove == "Y")) %>%
  select(-c("consec","remove"))
```

Answer (score 1):

A `base` R approach:

```
# split the dataframe by event into separate lists, record whether values are > 1 (T/F)
A_split <- split(A$Value > 1, Event)

# for each item in the list, record the number of consecutive T values;
# make T/F vector "keep" with row names corresponding to A$Event
keep <- sapply(A_split, function(x) sum(x[1:length(x) - 1] * x[2:length(x)])) == 0 

# convert keep to numeric vector of A$Event values
keep <- as.numeric(names(keep == T))

# subset A based on keep vector
A[A$Event %in% keep, ]
```